# One-Dimensional waves: $f(x - vt) = F \left( - \dfrac{x - vt}{v} \right) = F(t - x/v)$,

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

I am reading *Optics*, 5th edition, by Hecht, and I came across the following in chapter 2 when reading about one-dimensional waves.

$f(x - vt) = F \left( - \dfrac{x - vt}{v} \right) = F(t - x/v)$,

where $x$ is position, $v$ is speed, and $t$ is time.

I am assuming that $F$ has the usual meaning as denoting the antiderivative of $f$.

However, Hecht gives absolutely no justification for this claim.

I would appreciate it if someone could please take the time to justify this by demonstrating that it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like Hecht defines

$$F(u) \doteq f(-v u) \; . $$

There is no implication that $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.